# How to show that a real polynomial of degree $n$ is bounded on any finite interval?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $P(x)$ be a real polynomial of degree $n$. How to show that $P(x)$ is bounded on a finite interval, i.e. $\forall [a,b] \subset R, \exists L \in R, \max_{x \in [a,b]}P(x) < L$?

Comment: What do you think? Try to make an example of such a polynomial. If you succeed, great - you're done. If you don't, try to understand why.

Comment: Hint: Weierstrass theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Your polynomial $P$ is a continuous function, and continuous functions are bounded on bounded intervals.

A direct way to see this:
$$\left|P(x)\right|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^n c_kx^k\right| \leq \sum_{k=0}^n |c_kx^k|\leq\sum_{k=0}^n|c_k|\left(\max(|a|,|b|)\right)^k$$

Answer (score 1):

- Constant functions are bounded
- The identity function is bounded on a bounded interval
- The sum of two bounded functions is bounded
- The product of two bounded functions is bounded

Incidentally, the polynomials are the smallest set of functions that contains constants and the identity and is closed under sum and product.